# Why does runBlocking in main with only a coroutine fail to compile?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Using `kotlinc-jvm 1.3.61` and `kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.3.3`, the following code fails to compile.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {}
}
```

with error

```
Error: Main method not found in class SomeExampleKt, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

**however**, the following code compiles and runs successfully.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
fun main() = runBlocking {
    launch {}
    print("") // The only addition
}
```

Can anyone explain why adding just a `print` statement enables compilation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`main` function should not return anything (`Unit`). `runBlocking` returns its last statement value and `launch` returns `Job`, but `print` is a `Unit` function. Specifying a return value type may solve this problem.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
fun main() = runBlocking<Unit> {
    launch {}
}
```